# solr result grouping by query parts

Tags: solr, grouping

let's say I have the following solr query

```
(
    (name:("lasagne al forno")) // segment 1
OR 
    (name:("lasagne")) // segment 2
)
AND state:(1)
```

Is it possible to group search results by query segments?

I know that I can add boosting to either statement but I need to see which result item is coming from which segment.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you design your schema, you can use faceting and in particular: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_:_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting

Comment: thank you for the link, facets may help.